# Ignore NA scores function outlier package R

Tags: r, na, outliers

I want to ignore NA in a vector that I want to calculate the mscore.  I do not want to use na.omit as this will change the length of my vector that I need for other purposes later on.

What I have so far is:

```
library("outliers")

myvector <- c(0.00750,0.04750,0.06500,0.04750,0.0150,0.00750,0.210,0.02525,0.05750,NA)

mscore <- scores(myvector, "mad")
```

This produces all NA and there does not appear to be support for NAs in the scores function.

Without using `na.omit`, is there a work around?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write a new function that internally handles the NA entries:

```
scores_na <- function(x, ...) {
  not_na <- !is.na(x)
  scores <- rep(NA, length(x))
  scores[not_na] <- outliers::scores(na.omit(x), ...)
  scores
}

myvector <- c(0.00750,0.04750,0.06500,0.04750,0.0150,0.00750,0.210,0.02525,0.05750,NA)
scores_na(myvector, "mad")
 [1] -1.2125677  0.0000000  0.5304984  0.0000000 -0.9852112 -1.2125677
 [7]  4.9260561 -0.6744908  0.3031419         NA
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason you have all NAs is:

when you chose type = "mad",
"mad" gives differences between each value and median, divided by median absolute deviation.

There is one NA in myvector, therefore median is NA, and median absolute deviation is NA. That is why you have all NAs in mscore

Comment: Correct, but I want to ignore the NA so that the MAD value and subsequent calculations can be undertaken.  A lot of functions have built in provisions to ignore NA but the outliers package does not.  I could use na.omit to remove but I needed to keep the vector the same length for other purposes later on.